# Prove that the series $ \sum \frac{u_1 \ln(2) + u_2 \ln(3) + \dots + u_n \ln(n+1)}{n \ln(n) \ln(n+1)} $ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> $ \sum u_n $ is a convergent series with $ u_n \geq 0 $.
> $$v_n = \frac{u_1 \ln(2) + u_2 \ln(3) + \dots + u_n \ln(n+1)}{n \ln(n) \ln(n+1)} $$
> Prove that the series $ \sum v_n $ is convergent.

> Hint: Use the series $ \sum w_n $, with $ w_n = \frac{1}{\ln(n)} - \frac{1}{\ln(n + 1)} $

---

For $ n $ large enough we have: $ \ln(n + 1) \leq n$,

and for $ k \leq n$, we have: $u_k \ln(k + 1) \leq k u_k \leq nu_k $

$ \implies v_n = \frac{1}{n \ln(n) \ln(n+1)} \sum_{k = 0}^{n} u_k \ln(k + 1)\leq  \frac{1}{ \ln(n) \ln(n+1)} \sum_{k = 0}^{n} u_k $

How can I use the given hint to proceed? Thank you.

Comment: Try performing some kind of limit comparison test using $v_n$ and $w_n$.

Comment: @prets Would you elaborate more please?

Comment: First note that $\sum w_n$ converges (why?). Then try writing $w_n$ using common denominator, and study the size of the quotients $v_n / w_n$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @prets $\sum w_n$ converges because it is a telescoping series.

As suggested, $\frac{v_n}{w_n} = \frac{1}{n \ln(1 + \frac{1}{n})} \sum_{k = 0}^{n} u_k \ln(k + 1)$. I do not see how to proceed from here, can you clarify a bit more?